# How to get the file list with from a remote SFTP server in HH-MM-SS timestamp format

Tags: c++, sftp, libcurl

I'm writing a small app that reads the filelist from the remote sftp server using Curl. And while getting the files list and parsing it is not the problem:

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurlSession, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Callback);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurlSession, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://xxxx.xx:22/");
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurlSession, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "xxxx");
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurlSession, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "xxxx");
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurlSession, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, static_cast<long>(CURLUSESSL_ALL));
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurlSession, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_easy_perform(m_pCurlSession);
```

The output I get is this

```
drwxrwxr-x    3 root     root       4096 Jun 23 16:21 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root       4096 Jun 15 08:59 ..
drwxrwxr-x    2 user     user      4096 Jun 23 17:11 IMAGES
-rw-rw-r--    1 user     user    152069 Jun 23 16:20 test.xml
```

As you can see the timestamp of the last modified files is HH:MM, but since my app needs the compare the last modified of my local and remote file I also need to see the seconds so I can do the comparison.

When testing with FileZilla client, I can see the correct timestamp so I'm pretty sure it's not the server side issue.

How can I get the correct timestamp when issuing `LIST` using libcurl with SFTP?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that libcurl is good library for this.

Try libssh or libssh2:

- **libssh**: call `sftp_opendir` and then repeatedly `sftp_readdir` and finally `sftp_closedir`.

  You will get the full timestamp in `mtime` field of [`sftp_attributes_struct`](https://api.libssh.org/stable/structsftp__attributes__struct.html).
- **libssh2**: call [`libssh2_sftp_opendir`](https://libssh2.org/libssh2_sftp_opendir.html) and then repeatedly  [`libssh2_sftp_readdir`](https://libssh2.org/libssh2_sftp_readdir_ex.html) and finally [`libssh2_sftp_closedir`](https://libssh2.org/libssh2_sftp_closedir.html).

  You will get the full timestamp in `mtime` field of `LIBSSH2_SFTP_ATTRIBUTES`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by getting the file list, parsing to relevant file list and getting the each file timestamps separately.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It's only inefficient if there's an alternative.